# Why setTimeout is returning number values

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to get ***No list items*** only when there's nothing coming from the backend. Right now, onload, I get the loading spinner and ***No List items*** before I fetch the data.

So, I thought I would add a timeout to deal with this so that it will only show up after the fetching is done, and there are no items

```
 getList() {
        if(this.state.list.length != 0){
            return (this.state.list.map(data => {
              return <div data={data} key={data.id}/>
            }))
        }else{
            return <div>No List items</div>
        }
    }

render() {
        return (
            <div>  
                <Spinner active={this.state.active} />
                <div>{setTimeout(this.getList, 1000)}</div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

When i use this, I am getting numbers on the browser. The active state of spinner changes on componentDidMount to false

Comment: `setTimeout` returns an ID that can be passed to `clearTimeout`. `setTimeout` doesn't and cannot return the return value of the callback since `setTimeout` doesn't actually execute the function at the moment it is called. Using `setTimeout` in your situation doesn't make sense.

Comment: @FelixKling so what do you suggest, I should use to delay the "No list items" label before fetching is done. I fi cannot return the value

Comment: You can have `this.state.list` be `null` initially, which would mean that the data has not been fetched from the server yet. Or, assuming that `this.state.active` is `true` while the data is fetched and `false` once it is fetched, you can just do `{this.state.active ? null : this.getList()}`.

Comment: See my updated comment. Of course you wouldn't call `getList` if `this.state.list` is `null`. We don't know the rest of your code and what you do with `this.state.list` so we have to trust that you know how to apply the suggestion to your situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Items extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super();
        this.state = {
            active: true,
            is_loading: false,
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.timeout_number = setTimeout(() => {
            this.setState({
                active: false,
                is_loading: true
            });
        }, 1000);
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        clearTimeout(this.timeout_number);
    }

    getList() {
        if(this.state.list.length) 
            return this.state.list.map(data => <div data={data} key={data.id}/>)
        else
            return <div>No List items</div>
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>  
                <Spinner active={this.state.active} />
                {this.state.is_loading 
                    ? this.getList() 
                    : null}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Items;
```

Answer (score 4):

That's what setTimeout returns: an id number, which you can use later if you want to cancel the timeout.

The render method is synchronous. If you want to render nothing for the case where you don't have data, then you can have render return `null`. Then in componentDidMount, do any async work you need, and when it completes, call this.setState to update the state and rerender (this time without a `null`)

Comment: I want to render "No items" when i don't get anything

Comment: You can do that too. Perhaps start off with state = {list: null}, then fetch the data, then update the state to either have an empty array or a populated array. If list is null, render nothing. If list is empty, render the 'no items' message. If it's neither null nor empty, render the relevant divs.

Comment: Great, I will try this. Thanks for you response

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a timeout here.  I would just set the initial state of list to null.  Then just flip your logic so that it is:

```
getList() {
        if(this.state.list && this.state.list.length == 0){
            return <div> No List items </div>
        }else{
            return (this.state.list.map(data => {
              return <div data={data} key={data.id}/>
            }))
        }
    }
```

There are 100 ways to solve this but this is the easiest based on your code.  ALso don't forget the difference between != and !==.

Comment: Thank you for your response!